# What determines the amount of XP gained?

Tags: hearthstone

Every game mode seems to reward XP to the hero used, but the amount of XP seems to vary significantly. What factors influence the amount of XP granted? I can think of a few that likely influence it:

- play mode: Play, Practice or Arena
- regular or expert AI opponent
- victory or defeat
- length of the game
- did any player concede

Which factors actually play a role, and how important is each factor? Some numbers or a formula would be ideal, but I suspect that I might have to settle for some rough guidelines as no actual values are ever displayed in the game.

Comment: There is already a question for this (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139360/what-determines-how-much-experience-i-get-from-a-hearthstone-match-in-play-mode), but it has no answers and is from a few months ago, so I'm not sure if you'll get any answers for this or not.

Comment: Yeah this is sorta a duplicate question, although it does ask for more information then the first one which seems to focus only on the Play mode. I do wonder the same myself, the way the exp system works seems weird and sometimes I get bunch of exp for a win and sometimes almost no exp in a matches that last around the same amount of time.