# Conceding in Hearthstone

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone if you're losing a game you can simply concede and I was wondering if there is any logic behind it other than making an obvious loss end quicker. Does either player gain a little less XP or does just the conceder gain less XP, etc.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conceding in Hearthstone, as with any other game, causes you to immediately lose and end the game. It's for when you have no way of winning and allows you to move onto your next game without waiting for the inevitable.

Neither player is penalized for this, though players will earn less xp than they would by finishing the game as xp is (either directly or indirectly) based on the length of the game.

Comment: Thanks and I knew all of the first paragraph but your second paragraph did answer my question and added a bit of extra information, thanks again!

Comment: XP is mainly related to cards played (or mana spent), the actual length of the game as in minutes or turns passed seems to have no influence. See [this related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152768/68585).

Comment: Specifically, XP comes from wins, killing minions, and playing cards. If you're gonna lose, I think it's kosher to kill or play quickly and then concede. You are denying your opponent some XP, but there's no guarantee that the opponent cares about that as much as they do about their time.

Comment: Note that you get less XP *from the game* than you would have by playing it to completion; but the game is also over sooner.  You (and your opponent) may or may not end up with less XP *per unit time* if you resign.  It's probably neutral, if not slightly favourable for your opponent, based on the answer that @scenia links.

Answer (score 3):

In Hearthstone, if you concede, there are a few losses that can be incurred for one or the other. The first, as mentioned in Studoku's answer, is that the amount of xp will be a bit less, due to the length of a game being a factor of xp earned. In addition, if one player or the other has a quest such as: "Deal X Damage to your opponents." or "Play x 2 cost or lower minions", one player conceding might cause the player with this kind of quest to not progress quite as far in their quest as if you had just played it out. For example, often times if I'm going to win, and I have a quest like this, I will typically play out the winning turn such as playing a couple more 2 cost or lower minions, or playing a few more spells if doing so will advance my quest, rather than just killing my opponent at the start of the turn.

Answer (score 2):

There is no penalty for conceding. I generally concede if it is obvious that I am going to lose - why draw out a game when the result is obvious?

Comment: Keep in mind that you (or your opponent) could still make progress toward a quest, such as one to play a bunch of high mana creatures, even in a game where the outcome is obvious.  For this reason, I sometimes lower my defenses and allow my opponent to quickly win while potentially giving them progress toward a quest.

Comment: It also depends on how obvious is "obvious"? I've had opponents miss the fact that they have lethal damage on the board quite a few times.

Comment: @Coxy Agreed.  Remember, some (most?) players aren't as smart as other players give them credit for.  Giving someone the benefit of the doubt could mean that you missed an easy win because your opponent could have finished you but didn't for whatever reason.

Comment: I think conceding just before you lose is really lame. You should only concede if you're obviously going to lose in several turns, but not if you're going to lose in the next 10 seconds. Let people get the satisfaction of a victory well deserved.