# Exp calculation in HearthStone

Tags: hearthstone

How is experience calculated in HearthStone? I understand you get more exp for playing against people, but i can't find how to work out the exp gained.

Comment: I'm talking about in general, not specific modes.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is not a definitive answer. However, we do know (from testing and from developer statements) that experience per match is influenced by the following:

1. Number of cards played
2. Number of minions killed
3. Playing against a human seems to reward a modifier to these

A game in which one player concedes without playing a single card or killing a minion, even against a human, rewards very little to no exp.

Some wonderful people over at reddit did some thorough investigation and seem to have reverse-engineered a somewhat reasonable approximation, which can be read more at [What determines how much experience I get from a hearthstone match in play mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139360/what-determines-how-much-experience-i-get-from-a-hearthstone-match-in-play-mode?rq=1)

References: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Experience#Experience
https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/511582329874038784
http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/1nrxww/how_is_experience_gain_caluclated_in_hearthstone/cclklx4