# Is there any benefit of stretching out the kill shot?

Tags: hearthstone

Sometimes when I'm playing and I know that I'm going to get beat i.e.  my hero has 2 health left and my opponent already has sufficient minions to just kill it.
Why then, does he proceed to call 4 minions to the battlefield, do 6 spells and then kill all my minions before dealing the kill blow.

Why not just get it over with? I feel this is bad sportsmanship and in most cases I just concede.

What are the benefits and incentives for not immediately killing your opponent? Does the defeated player lose anything (e.g. rep) by conceding?

Comment: Why don't you concede when you know you're going to be beat?

Comment: I could, but feel it is part of the game to play to the end.

Comment: I think this question, and both the current answers, are entirely opinion based. Reframing it to be more objective like "Why not end the game as soon as you can?" might be better, but that is getting close to being a duplicate of other questions.

Comment: @Yule It's because they're an ass.

Comment: I do it sometimes just because I'm sad that I didn't have chance to use all those good carts that I finally got or sometimes to show enemy that they forgot about something they could have done previous round to avoid me from winning now.. sorry for my bad manners >.< On the other side if I see enemy doing the same I usually just concede, because I'm too mad to wait for longer loss. It's part of personal temperament I guess. You can call it being a douche/ss... totally up to you. + yes some might do it for the reasons in answers ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While in many cases it probably is just showing off and it is generally considered bad sportsmanship, playing cards and killing enemy minions is worth experience.

Additionally, Ravers points out that they may be trying to finish a quest, such as "Destroy 40 minions", "Play 40 spells", "Play 20 minions that cost 5 or more", or "Play 30 minions that cost 2 or less".

[What determines how much experience I get from a hearthstone match in play mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139360/what-determines-how-much-experience-i-get-from-a-hearthstone-match-in-play-mode)

Comment: And for that reason I often play everything I can before I concede. That way I am the one that get's more XP, not my enemy.

Comment: And sometimes its just for completing quests (i.e: use 40 spells, use 20 minions, etc)

Answer (score 9):

### How is this behaviour called?

The general term for the behaviour that you are describing is BM (short for "bad manners"). It is generally considered bad sportmanship, as already mentioned, but if you watch competitive Hearthstone you sometimes see players BM each other. The reason that this is OK, is because they know each other (maybe are even close friends) and take it as a joke. It is also quite entertaining for the viewers.

### What are the reasons for it?

On the ladder players may do it to show dominance, often accompanied by several Sorry-Emotes, but the most common reason is finishing [daily quests](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest#List).
 Maybe the xp-gain mentioned in the other answer plays a role too, but from my experience the it is all about finishing quests, like "Destroy 40 minions" or "Play 20 minions that cost 5 or most".

### How to handle?

Since Blizzard made the change that conceding the game is not part of the action-queue anymore, you can just concede to skip all the BM your opponent may throw at you.
 Before this change you would have to watch all your opponents actions if he queued them up before you pressed concede. Since they fixed this it is instant and saves you all that stuff. So best advice is to concede if you opponent has obvious lethal on the board.
 However, there are situations where you dont know if you are dead and your opponent does a lot of other stuff before he kills you with his topdecked fireball. In this case you cant do anything but stay calm and queue up for the next game :)

Answer (score 5):

Am I the only one who doesn't consider such behaviour bad manners? It's simply part of the game. Sometimes you want to be quick, sometimes you want to be absolutely sure and sometimes you want to feel the power rush coming with finally beating a tough opponent. Pick one or mix and mingle, there's plenty of reasons to stretch-out a game.

The major point to keep in mind is you can always get out by conceding. The other player isn't wasting your time. He's playing the game the way he wants to within the scope of the rules. If you disagree with his playing style there's nothing stopping you from conceding and moving on.

Comment: Not only that, I also consider it a nice gesture to show what cards they had in their hand, which sometimes tells the losing side how they should have played differently. As you say, if they want the game to end they can just concede.